# phone gap Back button control

Tags: android, html, cordova

I want to give a pop up when the back button will be clicked.Useing my code now back button is disable but it is not giving alert message.

```
function load()
{
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, false);
function backKeyDown() {console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");}
}

<body onLoad="load()">
</body>
```

Comment: Have you added the plugin `org.apache.cordova.App` to the `plugins.xml` ?

Comment: I am only using phone gap Html5

Comment: I understand that you are using PhoneGap. Did you read the getting started guide to android? It shows how you need to put a `plugins.xml` file in the `res/xml` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
function load()
{
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, false);
}

function backKeyDown() {

navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
}

function alertDismissed(){
history.back();
}
```